# Error inflating class fragment GoogleMaps

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I'm trying to implement Google Maps but keep getting this error:

AndroidRuntime Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

I've been trying to fix this for a few days, researched into it and had no luck.

My MainActivity.java file is:

http://pastebin.com/dWAkeULh

AndroidManifest.xml & activity_main.xml file:

http://pastebin.com/DGD8fRcZ

Thanks for any help it's much appreciated.

Apologies for the links, I know it's a pain but stressed and wasn't letting me paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I repaired it with changing this:

```
 googleMap  = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to this:

```
  googleMap  = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getMap();
```

In the layout change this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14"
/>
```

to this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still getting the same error as before.